# Conditional function for each element of a matrix

Tags: function, matlab, conditional-statements, element

I want to define a function y(x) as follows:

```
if x >= 0:     y = x^(1/2)
if x< 0:       y = NaN
```

I have tried below code, which clearly does not work.

```
y = @(x) (x>=0) * x.^(1/2) - NaN* (x<0); 
Test = y([-1,1,4,9])
```

My expectation is that:

```
y([-1,1,4,9]) = [NaN, 1, 2, 3];
```

In my limited understanding, `arrayfun` might help, but it would be very slow. Kindly help me a solution. Many thanks.

Edit. As pointed out by Cris Luengo, I did negligently not use wise-element `.*` in my question. Note that, even if using `.*`, my approach does not work.

```
y = @(x) (x>=0) .* x^(1/2) - NaN.* (x<0); 
Test = y([-1,1,4,9])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the code as given is that NaN times anything is NaN. NaN propagates through all calculations, by design; it's an error condition.

(Another problem with the code is that it computes the matrix multiplication and the matrix exponent. Use the element-wise operators `.*` and `.^` instead: `(x>=0) .* x.^(1/2)`.)

Typically you'd accomplish your goal in two lines:

```matlab
y = x.^(1/2);
y(x<0) = NaN;
```

But for this particular case we can create a NaN where `x<0` by dividing `x>=0` by itself: `(x>=0)./(x>=0) .* x.^(1/2)`. The result of the division is either NaN or 1, which multiplied by the square root of `x` yields either NaN or the square root of x.

Here I found yet another issue: `x.^(1/2)` is complex if any element of `x` is negative. So we need to take the real component of its result:

```matlab
y = @(x) (x>=0)./(x>=0) .* real(x.^(1/2));
```

---

The fastest way to compute this would need to be in a regular function (as opposed to an anonymous function as you have in the OP. It would look like this:

```matlab
function y = sqrt_or_nan(x)
y = nan(size(x));
index = x < 0;
y(index) = sqrt(x(index));
```

This avoids duplicate computations and unnecessary computations, and uses `sqrt` instead of `.^(1/2)` (which I presume is faster, though I haven't timed it).

Comment: It is truly an admirable art of your solution. Do you think it could be more concise in the sense of less calculation?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the element-wise operators. It is my negligence. Indeed, I do try to use `.*` in my solution, but of course, it fails to act as my expectation.

Comment: For example, I wonder whether `abs(x).^ (1/2)` is faster in calculation than `real(x.^(1/2))`?

Comment: @RomalpaAkzo That might be faster, yes, didn't think of that. ---- If you want this to be as fast as possible, you'd write it like what I just added to the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 2):

What is the purpose of having a function? If statement is hard to implement in an inline function. What about using relational operators like below?

```
x = [-1, 1, 4, 9];

x(x>=0) = x(x>=0).^(1/2);
x(x<0) = NaN;

>> x

x =

   NaN     1     2     3
```

Comment: Is that possible to put it as a function of x. I do need it as a function, given it would be referred many times in my code.